# How to install bower without connecting to internet?

Tags: node.js, npm, bower, bower-install

To be able to use the command `bower install`, first I have to install bower itself by the command `npm install -g bower`. This command, however connects to the internet. Is there a way to install bower without connecting to internet?

Comment: Not really. If you already have the files that comprise the bower package you could copy these into the correct place and have bower work. But without an internet connection, bower won't work (i.e. it won't be able to fetch any packages), so the question becomes "why would you want to do this?"

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying to use bower on an old laptop which cannot connect to internet. I saw something like [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/twitter-bower/1ELC149Qgjo) but couldn't understand the process. Was curious whether there is a simpler and more understandable way

Comment: And yes I already have the files on another laptop which works fine. Which part should I copy exactly?

Comment: Thing is, that even if you port bower from the good laptop to the one without an internet connection, that won't help you much, as bower will still need to connect to the internet to retrieve packages. You could attempt to set up a private registry (see here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/private-bower and here: https://medium.com/@juanpujol/setting-up-private-bower-f235a0942848), but again, without an internet connection, this will be problematic to say the least. If it was me, I'd probably set up what I need on the good laptop, then port the project (inc. node_modules) to the other machine.

Comment: I did not know that about bower. Seems it's not worth the trouble and I'd better do your advice. Thanks